# Google Chrome - block certain JavaScript function

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I have been searching around superuser for answers to this question but couldn't find anything that gave me the results I wanted.

**What happens**?
A script tag on a website is redirecting me to another page using window.location.href:

```
<script language="javascript">
  window.location.href = "index.php";
</script>
<head>...
```

**What I want to do**:
I want to be able to block only the window.location.href, but keep every other script working.

**What I have tried**:
Chrome Breakpoints(resets on page redirect),
NoScript (prevents Website from working properly)

Is this possible? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This belongs to stackoverflow..right?

Comment: Hm I think it is closer related to Google Chrome itself, but I'll have a look...